# Safari jumping halfway through my site. Any obvious causes?

Tags: html, safari

I've created   [1]: http://www.coltmanwebdev.com/SiS/index.html but some people are reporting their phone Safari browsers aren't displaying it from the start.

Have not come across this before and can't reproduce it. Does anyone have any advice? Many many thanks in advance

Comment: 1) Look in the console 2) validate the html using a validator 3) look in Chrome as if you are a mobile (seems to work there)

Comment: Thanks mplungjan - have already tried all this and am getting no errors at all. It seems ok on every other browser - really stumped